# What's this error - ReferenceError: count is not defined Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-grid

I am using Kendo UI Grid, but debug console showing error jQuery. I'm so tired I do not know what the problem is! Please look at this pic for error: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvJxO.png)

this mycode dont whtas error.iam debug code but dont find whats  error

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function () {
            var productsDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "@Url.Action("GridData", "Home")",
                       // url: "GridData",
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        type: 'GET',
                        data: { param1: "val1", param2: "val2" } // ارسال اطلاعات اضافي و سفارشي به سرور در حين درخواست
                    }
                },
            
                @*update: {
                    url: function (TUser) {
                        return "@Url.Action("UpdateProduct", "Home")/" + 20;;
                    },
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    type: "PUT"
                },*@
              
                //parameterMap: function(data, operation) {
                //    if (operation === "update" || operation === "create") {
                //       return JSON.stringify({ product: data });
                //    }
                //    return data;
                //},
           
                //parameterMap: function (options) {
                //    return kendo.stringify(options);
                //},
                error: function (e) {
                    alert(e.errorThrown.stack);
                },
                pageSize: 20,
                //sort: { field: "Id", dir: "desc" },
                schema: {
                    //...
                    model: {
                        //id: "UserName", // define the model of the data source. Required for validation and property types.
                        fields: {
                            "UserName": { type: "string", editable: false }, //تعیین نوع فیلد برای جستجوی پویا مهم است
                            "Name": { type: "string", validation: { required: true } }
                            //"IsAvailable": { type: "boolean" },
                            //"Price": { type: "number", validation: { required: true, min: 1 } },
                            //"AddDate": { type: "date", validation: { required: true } }
                        }
                    }
                },
                batch: true, 
            });

           $("#report-grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: productsDataSource,
                autoBind: true,
                scrollable: false,
                //pageable: true,
                pageable: {
                    previousNext: true, // default true
                    numeric: true, // default true
                    buttonCount: 5, // default 10
                    refresh: true, // default false
                    input: true, // default false
                    //pageSizes: true, // default false
                    pageSizes: [5, 10, 15, 20, 25,50,100], //array of page size choices for user
                    info: true // show a label with current paging information in it
                },
                //sortable: true,
                //filterable: true,
                //reorderable: true,
                //columnMenu: true,
                //groupable: true, // allows the user to alter what field the grid is grouped by
              
                //editable: {
                //    confirmation: "آيا مايل به حذف رديف انتخابي هستيد؟",
                //    destroy: true, // whether or not to delete item when button is clicked
                //    //mode: "popup", // options are "incell", "inline", and "popup"
                //    //template: kendo.template($("#popupEditorTemplate").html()), // template to use for pop-up editing
                //    //update: true, // switch item to edit mode when clicked?
                //    window: {
                //        title: "مشخصات محصول"   // Localization for Edit in the popup window
                //    }
                //},
                  
                columns: [
                    { field: "UserName", title: "شماره", width: "130px" },
                    {
                        field: "Name", title: "نام محصول",
                        footerTemplate: "تعداد: #=count#"
                    },
                     {
                         field: "Family", title: "نام محصول",
                         footerTemplate: "تعداد: #=count#"
                     },
                         {
                         command: [
                             //{ name: "edit", text: "ويرايش" },
                             { name: "destroy", text: "حذف" }
                           
                         ],
                         title: "&nbsp;", width: "260px"
                     }
                ],

      //          toolbar: [
      //{ name: "create", text: "افزودن ردیف جدید" },
      //{ name: "save", text: "ذخیره‌ی تمامی تغییرات" },
      //{ name: "cancel", text: "لغو کلیه‌ی تغییرات" },
      //{ template: kendo.template($("#toolbarTemplate").html()) }
      //          ],
                //messages: {
                //    editable: {
                //        cancelDelete: "لغو",
                //        confirmation: "آیا مایل به حذف این رکورد هستید؟",
                //        confirmDelete: "حذف"
                //    },

                //    commands: {
                //        create: "افزودن ردیف جدید",
                //        cancel: "لغو کلیه‌ی تغییرات",
                //        save: "ذخیره‌ی تمامی تغییرات",
                //        destroy: "حذف",
                //        edit: "ویرایش",
                //        update: "ثبت",
                //        canceledit: "لغو"
                //    }
                //}
            });
        });
    </script>
    @*<script>
    // اين اطلاعات براي تهيه خروجي سمت سرور مناسب هستند
    function getCurrentGridFilters() {
        var dataSource = $("#report-grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
        var gridState = {
            page: dataSource.page(),
            pageSize: dataSource.pageSize(),
            sort: dataSource.sort(),
            group: dataSource.group(),
            filter: dataSource.filter()
        };
        return kendo.stringify(gridState);
    }
    </script>*@

    <script id="toolbarTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
        @*<a class="k-button" href="\#" onclick="alert('gridState: ' + getCurrentGridFilters());">نوار ابزار سفارشي</a>*@
    </script>
    @*@RenderSection("JavaScript", required: false)*@
    @*<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="priceTemplate">
    </script>*@
```

Comment: Can you the post the code in jsFiddle ?

Comment: iam edit my code u see code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error was mostly caused by the kendo UI grid failing to get the field from data, in this case, "count".
I saw the count used here

```
{
    field: "Family", title: "نام محصول",
    footerTemplate: "تعداد: #=count#"
}
```

but I don't see any grouping or aggregate function used to have the count value. check more detail about using the footer template in [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.footerTemplate)